# Unable to verify correctly signed payload XERO webhook with Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, webhooks

Using Azure functions and I'm unable to send correct responce as per 
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/configuring-your-server

My code below:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');


const crypto = require('crypto')


const xero_webhook_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

const xero_header_key = req.headers['x-xero-signature'];

const payload = req.rawBody.toString();

const computedKey = crypto.createHmac('sha256', xero_webhook_key).update(payload,'utf8').digest('base64');


    if (computedKey === xero_header_key) {
        context.res = {
           status: 200,
        };
        context.log('status 200')
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
        };
        context.log('status 400')
    }

    context.log('x-xero-signature: '+xero_header_key)
    context.log('rawBody: '+req.rawBody)
    context.log('computedKey: '+computedKey)

};
```

Comment: The code seems fine.  Does it log that it's sending the response and Xero just isn't happy, or is it throwing an error?

Comment: XERO receives 400 responce on all requests. I believe they send 3 wrong header keys and the last one is the correct one, but my code only sends 400.

Answer (score 1):

just needed to add body:'' 
Found solution on below post
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2305